# Django Web App Heroku Deployement : No matching distribution found for decouple==0.0.7

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am deploying a web app made in Django on Heroku. 
I am following a tutorial in which tutor has made a w/s without any CSS / Image input from User. But my app has lot of style and profile pics etc which need ImageField in model.

IMP -> I made the project for Django 2.2, but django 3 got launched so I am using that.

***Please help me...***

I have done following steps:

1. Installed Anaconda
2. Made Virtual Env & Activated it.
3. Installed pip
4. Installed Dependencies
5. pip freeze > requirements.txt
6. git add . & git push -am "Text"
7. git push heroku master

My requirements.txt :

```
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
decouple==0.0.7
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.2
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-bootstrap3==12.0.3
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-mediumeditor==1.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
misaka==2.1.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
pycparser==2.19
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

My Error:

```
Enumerating objects: 18, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 1.96 KiB | 1.96 MiB/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Need to update SQLite3, clearing cache
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.2.3 (from -r /tmp/build_4f35d204f58c179bdbd37fc71a4afa61/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/cb/5a235b605a9753ebcb2730c75e610fb51c8cab3f01230080a8229fa36adb/asgiref-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting certifi==2019.11.28 (from -r /tmp/build_4f35d204f58c179bdbd37fc71a4afa61/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/df50cac98ea0d5b006c55a399c3bf1db9da7b5a24de7890bc9cfd5dd9e99/certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.13.2 (from -r /tmp/build_4f35d204f58c179bdbd37fc71a4afa61/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/72/0d42f94fe94afa8030350c26e9d787219f3f008ec9bf6b86c66532b29236/cffi-1.13.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (397kB)
remote:        Collecting decouple==0.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_4f35d204f58c179bdbd37fc71a4afa61/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement decouple==0.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_4f35d204f58c179bdbd37fc71a4afa61/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for decouple==0.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_4f35d204f58c179bdbd37fc71a4afa61/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to *******.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/******.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/******.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add a runtime.txt file at the root of your project with content:
python-3.7.2

And then push again.

Answer (score 0):

You use Python 3.6, `decouple` [requires](https://github.com/andrey-avdeev/decouple/blob/d49f78dbbed3c7884a3e08c1e3e236a459f48224/setup.py#L22) Python 3.7+.